# Strange contacts on my phone can't be deleted

Tags: contacts

I have had a contact on my phone appear from nowhere.  It is in an Arabic language not english. I have done a factory reset and downloaded my contacts from my gmail and it is not there immediately but arrives back a few minutes later.  I delete it and it comes back.  If I don't delete it right away I get a forced closed error.  any Idea where this could be hiding? and can I get rid of it.  Could it be on my sim card???

Comment: Is it possible you have a malicious app that is creating this rogue contact?!

Comment: I have done a factory reset and not downloaded any apps except the ones that come with the phone. The contact still shows up.  It is in my Motorola Services Contact.  There is no other information on the contact except  the name or whatever it is